# Finding all lines in text file beginning with a character then a space in php

Tags: php

I have a text file and in it i want to only read the lines that start with an r then a space.
I have tried strpos but it does not seem to work.

```
$r="r ";  
$file = file_get_contents('cached-consensus', true);  
$n = explode("\n", $file);  
foreach($n as $line){  
$pos= strpos($line,$r);  
echo $pos;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem to work"?  That doesn't help anyone answer you.  How do you know if it works or not?  What does `$pos` equal?  `0` means it's the beginning of the string.

Comment: post sample data also

Comment: `if (strpos($line,$r) === 0)` - use type-specific value check; otherwise 0 == false

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('cached-consensus', true);  
$n = explode("\n", $file);  
foreach($n as $line){  
    if(0 === strpos($line, "r ")){
        // do whatever you want with the line
    }
}
```

This checks that `$line` starts with 'r '. Currently you're just echoing the position of the string (this should be `0`).